# Why is Python returning None instead of value

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, math

another one of these stupid questions.
I have a very simpe algorithm here to calculate the greatest commen divider.

My C++ snippet looks like this

```
int findGcd(int m, int n)
{
    int r = m % n;

    if(r == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    else
    {
        m = n;
        n = r;
        findGcd(m, n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << findGcd(13, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

... And it returns (exactly as expected in this example) 1.

If I implement it in Python though - like the following:

```
def findGcd(m, n):
"""Calculates the greatest common divider """
    r = m % n

    if r == 0:
        return n

    else:
        m = n
        n = r
        findGcd(m, n)




number = findGcd(13,3)
print(number)
```

It just returns     NONE  instead of 1. I already debugged it and n did indeed have the correct value of 1 stored in it but returns None none the less.

I can fix this by adding "return" to my recursive call of the function in the else branch.
But why is that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output in C++

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that's because, in C++, the missing `return` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I was using an online C++ compiler. Turns out it was s#*t. Sorry for wasting your time on this one. The misunderstanding was just caused by the compilers unexpected behaviour.
Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Note, there *are* languages that have return statements that *will* implicitly return, e.g. Scala. You shouldn't assume, though, that because something works in C++ (or in this case, it didn't) or Scala that it will work in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you need a `return` in the recursive call.

Without that, in C++, you have undefined behavior. In Python, you get `None`.

C++

```
int findGcd(int m, int n)
{
    int r = m % n;

    if(r == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    else
    {
        m = n;
        n = r;
        return findGcd(m, n);
    }
}
```

Python:

```
def findGcd(m, n):
"""Calculates the greatest common divider """
    r = m % n

    if r == 0:
        return n

    else:
        m = n
        n = r
        return findGcd(m, n)
```

You catch such problems in C++ by increasing the warning level on your compiler. With `g++ -Wall`, I get:

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int findGcd(int, int)’:
socc.cc:16:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```